# Google maps - move embed to static

Tags: google-maps, static, routes, embed

So, i have custom route on my map. I put in on my web (local page to be precise). Unfortuently, on high dpi screen texts are very tiny. I've found static maps to be able to rescale map (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) but have no idea how to show my custom route on static map (route was generated from GPX file).

Is there any way to do it?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after few hours of research i've found that i need to convert gps coords into polyline, ie. https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-csv-polyline-encoder.htm
It generates example link for google maps.